# Let me comment my top answers in Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

In the Developer Story, you can add summaries or comments to most of the entry types, even to blogs and videos. However, you can not comment on the top answers you chose to show. Often, you don't just want show off your highest scoring answers - those can easily be found anyways - but you'd like to show off an answer you find especially good, where you put large amounts of work in, where you made an excellent in-depth explanation (and not just a "here are teh codez").

Right now, you can't tell anybody *why* this answer is so special. With a short explanation, as visualised in the image below, the top answers would become equally important parts of the developer story, and not just those bullet points you quickly scroll over.

**tl;dr:** Please let me add a short comment to my top answers, so I can tell everybody *why* I think this answer is so amazing!!

[image: Proposed comment on a top answer]

Comment: I was curious why there was only a link and nothing more as well. It would be nice to have some annotation.

Comment: You ask for annotation, and yet there is a lack of hand-drawn red in your screenshot...

Comment: Would't part of this comment also fit into the answer?

Comment: Agree with MrTux. These comments should be part of the answer too :) Impresses beginners.

Comment: @NateBarbettini This has been fixed.

Comment: @NateBarbettini I hope I could clarify the request ;-)

Comment: @MrTux I agree that sometimes a short summary can be appropriate to make the intention clear. But there are two different targets: 1) a reader who wants a problem solved, so you tell him why this answers his question and why he needs this background info, or 2) a potential employer, whom you want to show why this answer is representative of your abilities. While 1) clearly goes into the answer, 2) should be the proposed comment in your developer story.

Comment: @hbaderts:  I'm of the influence that there is no difference between 1 and 2...a phenomenal answer will demonstrate the kind of flare that you want to show off to a potential employer without needing to fluff it up or add any extra details.

Comment: @Makoto Sometimes an exceptional answer can be provided to a not-so-good question (or not-so-well-titled question). An employer might not want to look that deep when seeing a weird/boring question title in the Developer Story (some titles may even put you in a bad light "this guy answers such dumb questions?"), but being able to add a small summary to clarify what is exceptional in there may lead to the employer looking at that.

Comment: This is interesting.  The team is currently working on fixing bugs but this is something they will look at and/or consider once time allows.

Comment: @Bakuriu, While I agree being able to annotate would be good and there can be issues with a question to which you post a good answer, you are encouraged to edit the question to be good (there are badges for doing so). That includes things like changing the title to better reflect the question. Obviously, there is only so much you can do and still maintain the intent of the OP who asked the question. However, there is often a large amount that you can, and should, do to improve a question, particularly if you are wanting to have that question/answer be part of what represents you to employers.

Comment: Thanks so much for the freehand circles. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @hbaderts thanks for the suggestion, it's a good idea. We're planning to add a description to top answers soon. I'll keep you posted with progress.

Comment: @Kit are there any updates on this so far?

Comment: I've removed the status-review tag from this post, since the Developer Story feature no longer exists.